# Synonym of "scrap" in the given econtext

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is a description of a battle game from the Internet:

> Once you take a good amount of damage, it will cost hundreds and
>   eventually thousands of **scrap**. But you can bypass this entirely with
>   one 300 **scrap** health power-up. The difference is that you need to
>   equip it to one of your power-up slots and use it during gameplay, but
>   so what? It is insanely cheap. Likewise, you never really know where
>   to spend your money, either on new guns or upgrading, and it’s a total
>   crapshoot with almost everything being unlocked from the start. And
>   most of these things are pretty expensive.
>
> This lack of direction leads to weird pacing. Once you upgrade your
>   chassis the first time, you’ll gain access to the second area of the
>   game, along with your 2 new gun slots. This is where the game becomes
>   truly fun, as you get much more **scrap** and can experiment more
>   frequently.

Here I am looking for an easier synonym of the word "scrap" to make a similar texts easier for my target readers who are not well versed with game's terms.

Comment: It sounds like *scrap* is just the name of the in-game currency. Replacing it with something else while the game calls its in-game currency *scrap* would lead to more confusion. A better way to make it more understandable to new people is just to mention early on that *scrap* is an in-game currency.

Comment: I found [the site](https://toucharcade.com/2016/07/15/mega-tank-review/) where this came from.  It looks like **scrap** in this context means **units of scrap metal**, since that's what you're collecting in the game.  I don't know what to suggest, frankly.  **Scrap** (meaning discarded bits of metal suitable for recycling) is a common and well-understood English world; but in the real world it doesn't come in identical units and is not used as a count noun. This is a very artificial in-game concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **[scrap](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/scrap)** (n): 2 Discarded metal for reprocessing.  2.1 Any waste articles or discarded material.

It sounds like when you destroy enemies in the game they they drop "scrap", which you can then collect and later use to upgrade your vehicle.  The exact nature of the scrap is not important -- it's just used as a kind of in-game currency, as certain upgrades will *cost* a certain amount of scrap.

Many games use a similar scrap mechanic, although they might use a different term for it.